# datepicker opens after ajax call on second click? how to open it on first click?

Tags: php

before ajax call I write the code for date picker is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#birthdate").focus(function() {
            $(this).datepicker().datepicker( "show" )
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $("#joindate").focus(function() {
            $(this).datepicker().datepicker( "show" )
        });
    });
    </script>
```

this function called after onfocus event:

```
<tr>
              <td align="left">
                <input type="text" id="birthdate"  name="birthdate"  onfocus="$('#birthdate').datepicker({changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',defaultDate: '-20y -1m -247d',yearRange: '-50:+0'});"   tabindex="14"  style="width:300px; "   value="<? if($get_emp!='0')echo $employee_birth; ?>" /><span style="color:#F00;">*</span></td>                                       

    <td>
        <input type="text" name="joindate" id="joindate" onfocus="$('#joindate').datepicker({changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',defaultDate: '-3y -1m -247d',yearRange: '-50:+0'});"  tabindex="15" style="width:300px; " value="<? if($get_emp!='0')echo $employee_join; ?>"/><span style="color:#F00;">*</span>
        </td>
     </tr>
```

after ajax call I call the same code but it not opens on first click , however it opens on second click?
please help me to sort out this problem..........................

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript. You only need to initialize the `datepicker()` once

```
$(function() {
    $('#birthdate').datepicker({changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',defaultDate: '-20y -1m -247d',yearRange: '-50:+0'});
    $("#joindate").datepicker({changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',defaultDate: '-3y -1m -247d',yearRange: '-50:+0'});
    $("#birthdate, #joindate").focus(function() {
        $(this).datepicker( "show" )
    });
});
```

I removed the focus attribute from the input tags:

```
<input type="text" id="birthdate"  name="birthdate" tabindex="14"  style="width:300px; "  value="<? if($get_emp!='0')echo $employee_birth; ?>" /><span style="color:#F00;">*</span></td>                                       

<input type="text" name="joindate" id="joindate" "  tabindex="15" style="width:300px; " value="<? if($get_emp!='0')echo $employee_join; ?>"/><span style="color:#F00;">*</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#joindate").datepicker({
        // Options and methods here
    });
    $("#joindate").focus(function(){
          $("#joindate").datepicker("show");
    });
    $("#joindate").focus();
});
```

You can also do a $.post() on the "onSelect" event, should you want to post the date on the actual click event of the date, instead of having to tie it to a form submit.